# Redux - Jest: Testing functions that have void return

Tags: redux, mocking, jestjs, redux-thunk

New to Jest and Redux and I'm having trouble with testing functions that are dispatching to the store but don't yield a return value. I'm trying to follow the example from the [Redux website](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) does this

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos()).then(() => {
      // return of async actions
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
})
```

however I have several "fetchtodos" functions that  don't return anything which causes the error **TypeError**:

> `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined due to returning undefined`

I'm wondering what I can do to test that my mock store is correctly updating. Is there a way to dispatch the function, wait for it to finish and then compare the mock store with expected results?

Thanks

---

**Edit: We're using typescript**

**action from tsx**

```
export function selectTopic(topic: Topic | undefined): (dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<TopicState>) => void {
  return (dispatch: Redux.Dispatch<TopicState>): void => {

    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_Topic,
      payload: topic,
    });

    dispatch(reset(topic));
  };
}
```

**test.tsx**

```
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('Select Topic action', () => {
  it('should create an action to select .', () => {
    const topic: Topic = mockdata.example[0];
    const expectedAction = {
      type: actions.SELECT_TOPIC,
      payload: topic,
    };

    const store = mockStore(mockdata.defaultState);

    return store.dispatch(actions.selectTopic(topic)).then(() => {
      expect(store.getState()).toEqual(expectedAction);
    });
  });
});
```

The action is what I'm given to test(and there are many other functions similar to it. I'm getting that undefined error when running the test code, as the function isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, the store's `dispatch` method is synchronous unless you attach middleware that changes that behavior, ie: returns a promise.

So this is likely a redux configuration problem. Be sure you are setting up your test store with the same middleware that allows you to use the promise pattern in production.

And as always, be sure to mock any network requests to avoid making api calls in test.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So our codebase had the ReduxThunk middleware applied to it. I'm using the redux-mock-store library and configure the mockstore with said middleware. Give me a moment to update my quest with more generalized code.